# Overwriting ScaledSheet styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm using a custom input field which already has its styles. When using it in one particular screen, I want to change the width and height. Is it possible to overwrite the styles?

To overwrite the existing styles, I added a new property to the existing styles of that page

```
field: {
    width: moderateScale(300, 0.3),
    height: verticalScale(40),
  },
```

However, it doesn't make a difference.

This is from my main page:

```
return (
    <Modal
      visible={showPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.searchTopContainer}>
            <View style={styles.searchTopTextContainer}>
              <Text
                style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}
                onPress={toggleShowPage}>
                Cancel
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchTopMiddleText}>
                Add Friend by Email
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}>
                Done
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({
                  handleChange,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleSubmit,
                  values,
                }) => (
                  <View>
                    <View style={styles.form}>
                      <FieldInput style={styles.field}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                        fieldType="email"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage 
                        name="email"
                        render={(msg) => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                            {msg}
                          </Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        rounded
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>
                          Add Friend{' '}
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

While the FieldInput consists of this:

```
return (
    <Item rounded style={styles.personalListItem}>
      <Icon name="envelope" size={moderateScale(20)} color="green" />
      <Input
        autoFocus={true}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        style={{ fontSize: moderateScale(15) }}
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        keyboardType="default"
        onChangeText={handleChange(fieldType)}
        onBlur={handleBlur(fieldType)}
        value={value}
        secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
      />
      {togglePassword ? (
        <Icon
          name={hidePasswordIcon}
          onPress={togglePassword}
          style={commonStyles.iconStyle}
          size={moderateScale(20)}
          color="green"
        />
      ) : null}
    </Item>
  );
```

and has this styling:

```
  personalListItem: {
    width: moderateScale(320),
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderRadius: moderateScale(10),
    height: verticalScale(50),
    paddingRight: moderateScale(20),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(10),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(20),
  },
```

For styling, I am using **ScaledSheets** from **react-native-size-matters**. I don't want to switch to another method since all the remaining styling has been done like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case, but it seems to me that you're using react-native-size-matters.

I'm not familiar with that, but what I can tell you is that you can achieve what you want if you start using `styled-components`.

Not only can you override CSS, you can also define media queries at component level.

When using `styled components` you do things like this :

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
     padding: 20px;
  }
`;
```